# Update data from one table to another using rownum

Tags: oracle

I have one table temp_name and it has seq_no , first_name,last_name and now I have another table called BEN_NAME in that also there is field first_name, last_name. I have to update the BEN_NAME table from the first_table by matching seq_num = rownum(of ben_name) table

Comment: That doesn't sound right; `rownum` (of `ben_name` table) is purely random, and the row number values may not match the `seq_num` in the first table.

Comment: Please, try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Even it is random that does not matter in my requirement just update should happen because in random name table names are random.

Comment: If it does not matter, then why can't you copy `temp_name` over `ben_name`? `drop table ben_name; create table ben_name as select first_name, last_name from temp_name`. It is certainly much more efficient than what you are considering.

Comment: it's not a good practice to update by rownum and really error prone